# Selenium JavascriptExecutor: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascriptexecutor

When trying to use this format of selector with SeleniumJavascriptExecutor:

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].textContent=${value}", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('div.stb-LazyChosenDropdown div.tiles div.input:nth-child(1)')))
```

The following error is thrown:

```
org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Yet it works without the `:nth-child(1)` part just fine so I'm inclined to think it doesn't like the `(1)` in the string which my IDE seems to think is an integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell what language that is but it should probably look like this:

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].innerText = arguments[1]", element, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `nth-of-type(1)` instead of `nth-child(1)`

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].textContent=${value}", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('div.stb-LazyChosenDropdown div.tiles div.input:nth-of-type(1)')))
```

Comment: this doesn't work unfortunately.  The selector I used is fine I think, it's just Javascript Executor doesn't like the (1) token in the selector

Answer (score 0):

This *cssSelector*:

```
input:nth-child(1)
```

selects the `<input>` element that is the first child of its parent can be replaced with:

```
input:first-child
```

which will also select the `<input>` element that is the first child of its parent.

Effectively the [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) will be:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector('div.stb-LazyChosenDropdown div.tiles div.input:input:first-child'))
```

Comment: thanks that makes sense but it still throws the same error unfortunately